# Dafny call may violate context's modifies clause when using factory pattern

Tags: dafny

When calling methods which modify fields in a class, I get an error iff the class was created with a factory:

```
class Counter {
    var i: int;
    constructor() {
        i := 0;
    }
    method Count()
        modifies this
    {
        i := i + 1;
    }
}

method CounterFactory() returns (r: Counter)
{
    r := new Counter();
}

method Main() {
    var counter := CounterFactory();
    counter.Count(); // <~~ Error: call may violate context's modifies clause
}
```

When I replace the line directly above the error with `var counter := new Counter();`, the verifier doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

`CounterFactory()` needs a postcondition to show that the returned object is new. The working method looks like this:

```
method CounterFactory() returns (r: Counter)
    ensures fresh(r)
{
    r := new Counter();
}
```